# Javascript Proxy, howto trigger trap from inside of your target

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

When creating a proxy in javascript like this

```
var t = function() {
    self = this;
    this.a = "abc";
    someFunc: function () {
        self.a = "def";
    }
}

target = new t();

var p = New Proxy(target, {
  set: function(){
         //this will never be called when the someFunc changes the a field.
       }
})


p.someFunc();
```

the set "trap" will never be called I have no problem understanding why this happens, but how should one solve such a situation?

One solution would be to expose the self variale to the outside, and let "someone" change it to the proxy, not very obviouse for anyone using the t object....

Is there any other way? 
Am I misusing the proxy?

Comment: "*One solution would be to expose the self variale to the outside*" - [you already do that](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)? Add a `var`! And also fix all the other syntax errors like `someFunc:` or `New`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be not to use `self` at all:

```
function T() {
    this.a = "abc";
    this.someFunc = function () {
        this.a = "def"; // `this` in the method (usually) refers to the proxy
    };
}

var p = new Proxy(new T, {
    set: function(target, key, value, receiver) {
        console.log(key, value);
        return Reflect.set(target, key, value, receiver);
    }
});
p.someFunc();
```

If `someFunc` does not use the proxy, you cannot force it to without rewriting your `T`.

Comment: That is probably the "issue" here, that someFunct does not know anything about the proxy, and it shouldn't either. That is part of the proxy concept i guess.

Comment: @PEtter Well yes it is, now what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?